# Constexpr placement new?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, placement-new

The C++ standard specifically bans calling `new` in a constant expression (N4296 section 5.20 [expr.const]):

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> ...
>
> — a new-expression (5.3.4);

This ban (as far as I can see) extends to *all* forms of `new`, including placement new. However, since placement new doesn't actually allocate any memory and merely runs constructors at the given location, and since it's legal to take the address of a variable in a `constexpr` context (indeed, `std::addressof` will be constexpr in C++17), it seems to me that this prohibition could (in principle at least) be eased to allow placement new in constexpr functions.

So my question is, am I missing something? Is there a good reason why placement new is forbidden in `constexpr` functions?

(For context: the current rules pretty much require that constexpr-enabled sum types like `std::variant` are implemented as a recursive union. It would be nicer to be able to use something like `std::aligned_storage` and placement new, but currently that's not possible.)

Comment: "It would be nicer to be able to use something like `std::aligned_storage` and placement new" I don't think so, and given that reinterpret_cast is banned in constant expression, I don't think you can implement `std::variant` in this way even with constexpr placement new.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/_s7vi9pOhfY

Comment: @T.C. You should really summarize that discussion as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no conceptual reason that placement new couldn't work. I suppose this was an oversight, placement new is basically just a call to the constructor in a predefined memory location.

Ensuring the placement new parameter has a valid argument location isn't any harder than ensuring a write to random pointer is valid.

Comment: one of reason that such things would not work is presence of canadian crosses and simply cross-compilers. It becomes night-impossible to deduce behaviour with those

Answer (score 1):

Placement new do not mix well with the curent `constexpr` world, because it allows to build an object with its underlying byte representation (with value-initialization). And this is not defined in the standard (two-complement is not even in constexpr, as reminder)

Looking at C++ standard discussions, it could alternatively allow to peek into the object type representation afterwards (as you still hold the byte array)