# Can a constexpr class have uninitialized but inaccessible objects?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

I'm a little unclear if I could have an object that has uninitialized values that are not accessible.

E.g.: Say like a stack based on an c-array.  If I don't have any elements in the stack, then the elements stored could be uninitialized, but when I push an element onto the stack, I would use placement new to use the copy constructor and on pop, I would placement delete.

Actual access to the elements beyond the head of the stack would not be accessible, or accessing them would be UB (just like elements beyond the actual c-array).

Comment: You'll need to move on to C++20 for that.

Comment: Thx @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica. Just verifying.

Comment: No placement new in constexpr anyways. You'll need [`std::construct_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at) from C++20

Comment: That's interesting @Artyer.  Why did they do that rather than put a `constexpr` on the placement new?  I'm going to have to look into this further.  Thx for the info.

Comment: @Adrian This is a good explanation for why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74035713 (TLDR: some existing implementations would have difficulty using placement new during constant evaluation, it's easier to just make a separate function)